# Moving Mail to Outlook Sent Folder. Mail is still editable

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am editing an email and send it to the recipient. But i also want to save the original mail in the sent folder. But if i move the **`mailobject`** to the folder the mail is still editable.

[image]

This is how i move the mail:

```
  private void CopyMailToSent(Outlook.MailItem originalMail)
  {
      var folder = originalMail.SaveSentMessageFolder;
      originalMail.Move(folder);          
  }
```

Can i set the mailobject to readonly or faking the send?

Comment: why manually copy to sent, why not just enable the option in outlook to do that for you then, rather than moving the mail to sent - you would actually just send it..

Comment: I am editing the mail, add some text to it and remove the attachments. The edited mail will be sent to a person but the original mail should also be in the sent folder for archiving

Comment: Move copy rather then moving the original mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Outlook Object Model would not let you set the `MailItem.Sent` property at all. On the MAPI level, the `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit in the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` property can only be set before the message is saved for the very first time.

The only OOM workaround I am aware of is to create a post item (it is created in the sent state), set its message class to "IPM.Note", save it, release it, reopen by the entry id (it will be now MailItem in the sent state), reset the icon using PropertyAccessor, set some sender properties (OOM won't let you set all of them).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, it will let you set the `Sent` property as well as the sender related properties, plus add recipients without having to resolve them.

```
Set MySession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
MySession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Set folder = MySession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set msg = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note")
msg.Sent = True
msg.Recipients.AddEx "Joe The User", "joe@domain.demo", "SMTP", olTo
msg.Sender = MySession.CurrentUser
msg.SentOnBehalfOf = MySession.CurrentUser
msg.subject = "Test sent message"
msg.Body = "test body"
msg.UnRead = false
msg.SentOn = Now
msg.ReceivedTime = Now
msg.Save
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Redemption is unfortunately not an option. Could you please give me some example code for the "OOM post item" workaround?

Comment: Which part? Call MAPIFolder.Items.Add(olPostItem), PostItem,.MesageClass = "IPM.Note", PostItem.Save

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem but i did workaround which works fine for me. 
I hope it's ok to post this here even it's not right the solution. If not, sorry i will delete it.

My workaround is saving the orignal mail as ".msg" file and then add it to the mail in the sent folder. 
Then it looks like this:
[image]

This is the code:

```
private void SendMail(Outlook.Mailitem mail)
{
   mail.SaveAs(tempDirectory + @"originalMail.msg");
   var folder = mail.SaveSentMessageFolder;  
   ChangeMailSubject(mail);
   ChangeMailText(mail);
   mail.Send();
   folder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler((sender) => AttachOriginalMail(sender);    
}

private void AttachOriginalMail(object sender)
{   
    var mail = (Outlook.MailItem) sender;
    mail.Attachments.Add(tempDirectory + @"originalMail.msg");
    mail.Save();
}
```